# Meteor directory structure

Tags: meteor

### Can someone specify the best practices for Directory Structure of a Meteor App?

I am new to Meteor and having a hard time getting things right while placing files in the app directory.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: You could also check out a Meteor boilerplate made by Differential. It has an interesting, very meteor-specific way of structuring the directories & files. You can find it here: https://github.com/Differential/meteor-boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use a simple shell script to scaffold new Meteor projects. This should be easy to adapt to your own needs.

```
mkdir client
mkdir client/helpers
mkdir client/scripts
mkdir client/stylesheets
touch client/stylesheets/style.css
mkdir client/templates
mkdir lib
mkdir lib/collections
touch lib/router.js
mkdir public
mkdir public/fonts
mkdir public/images
mkdir server
mkdir server/collections
mkdir server/crons
mkdir private
```

Comment: No I haven't! Thanks for the tip!